# Is there a way to show warning for NSString properties if the attribute "copy" is not used?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is it true that for any properties of classes that has a subclass that is mutable, it is better to use `copy` as attribute, so for `NSString`, an `NSMutableString` can be passed in, and `NSString` can gladly accept it, so it is better to use `copy` so that the mutable string cannot change the content behind the back of the `NSString property?

If so, is there a compiler warning setting that can signal such cases, saying `copy` might be used instead of `strong` or `assign`?

Comment: It is true that copy is advisable for *most* cases. However, there might be times when you would need the `NSString` to reference the passed object, not copy it, thus a compiler warning is out of the question.

Comment: In general, the compiler has no way to tell if an object is the mutable variety or not.